# Getting this error: "ReferenceError: csv is not defined"

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types, referenceerror

Getting error "**ReferenceError: csv is not defined**". Not able to figure out the reason. Need some help solving this error.

```js
function csvfiletest() {
  var csv1 = [
   ['Alan Walker', 'Singer'],
   ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'Footballer'],
   ['Saina Nehwal', 'Badminton Player'],
   ['Arijit Singh', 'Singer'],
   ['Terence Lewis', 'Dancer']
   ];
  var fileName = 'Orders.csv';
  DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csv1, MimeType.text/csv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- `MimeType.text/csv` is `MimeType.CSV`.
- When you want to create a CSV file, it is required to convert from the array to the CSV data.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csv1, MimeType.text/csv);
```

#### To:

```
DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csv1.map(r => r.join(",")).join("\n"), MimeType.CSV);
```

#### References:

- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content,-mimetype)